# 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' error and node modules folder not showing up in vs code

Tags: node.js, json, node-modules, web-development-server

When I try to run my app.js on my localhost using node, i get this error: Error: Cannot find module ;  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []

I know it is not a problem with the extension being excluded in my vs code settings. Other projects show the node modules folder except this one. Additionally, I have removing and reinstalling both node js, and vs studio but nothing is working.

I downloaded this project folder from a web dev course and one person in the comments suggested to update the dependencies using the command

```
npm i -g npm-check-updates
ncu -u
npm install
```

The update commands generates these errors:

> npm ERR! code EACCES
>
> npm ERR! syscall mkdir
>
> npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm-check-updates
>
> npm ERR! errno -13
>
> npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm-check-updates'

I also typed the updated dependency versions manually but that didn't fix the issue either. Please help

Comment: I found a solution. The issue was that i needed to set correct permissions (ownership) so npm can access my directories without admin permisisions required. I use this code:                                                                               
     " sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm " &                                                                            
     " sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local/lib/node_modules"